# Unused import directive in Android after using widget in code

Tags: android

I am beginning to learn Java through book, and its guiding me through Android Studio.  Unfortunately Android now uses Kotlin so some things are confusing.  I am getting an unused import directive error, and cannot declare variables from the GUI widgets.  Screen shot below shows my problem:
[image]

any help is sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText` declaration is invalid for Kotlin.
A valid declaration can be:

```
private lateinit var txtGuess: EditText
```

By the way, since you are using KotlinX synthetic, you can refer directly to your view in your Kotlin code using the id specified in the XML layout `R.layout.activity_main` and removing `EditText txtGuess` with its import.